# Cycles: glossy material is too dark

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, light

I am new in Cycles render engine and node edit, now I want to try a simple scene with a bright steel.Here is my scene: [image]The plane behind camera has the same angel as the camera because the cube is specular reflection to light.The strength of it is set to 1.600. However, it do not make any affect at all.

[image]
As you can see in the second screenshot, I want the render result(Bottom left) is as bright as the one in Preview(right, although i do not think the preview is bright enough, think of the steal, it should be more closer to silver). And the texture of the steal don't have any affect is a mystery for me as well(I want some scratches on the cube just like an anpolished steal in the real world), do I make a mistake in the node editor?

Comment: Related link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50576/1853

Comment: I know you've found an alternative solution, but anyway... In the above screen shot your Mix Shader is set at half Glossy and half Diffuse. Does sliding that closer to the Glossy side give you the effect you were hoping for?

Comment: In your world tab, is your surface color very dark by any chance? If so, try setting to white. Hope that helps (: Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your node tree looks right, here's a list of things that *might* be wrong, it's hard to know from the screenshots alone. Try providing a little more info:

1. I have not seen your image but, It should probably be using *Texture Coordinate > UV* as vector input not a *Normal* node.
2. If you want it to affect scratches on the surface it should be connected with a "Bump" node to the "Displacement" socket, not diffuse.
3. There is also nothing to reflect in your scene so your glossy object will only reflect the dark background. Give it some context or other objects to reflect, and a more interesting less flat geometry.
4. Your scene looks dark because there seems to be insufficient light, can you show us your light setup?

Also consider using an *Anisotropic Shader* instead of diffuse/glossy/texture, it's probably easier for a first time learning.

Comment: To the point 4, have a look at the render result in my answer, I do not change the light setting a lot from which in my question, so I do not think the light setting caused the problem. Also, I have try to put a point light close to the cube, not much affect at all.

Comment: From the link by @cegaton , I found the glossy hard to reflect point light. I may try out some big emission plane.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my own way to solve my problem, I do not know if it is the best way.
[image]
Here is the result:
[image]