# Create a square Ocean

Tags: ocean-simulation

I'm currently creating a video for an art installation and I want to make a square ocean.
Let me explain, for the moment i'm using the ocean modifier on a plane but during the generation the ocean take an S shape and i'd like it to stay as square as possible.

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I'd like:

[image]

And finally last question, do you have any idea to add more light to this scene because, as you can see, it's a bit dark.

Thank you very much !

PS: I'm french so excuse me for my bad english

Comment: Related, specifically [Point 3 on my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52701/cycles-glossy-material-is-too-dark)

Comment: As for the darkness of the glossy material, you need something to reflect...try an HDRI made by Greg Zaal from here: https://hdrihaven.com/

Comment: also add a little bit of diffuse shading to imitate the effect of scattered light rays in the water