# Rendered glossy texture does not match preview

Tags: texturing, shaders

I have a problem with a texture/Shader. The Mesh was created from a bezier curve.

[image: Texture Preview]

Above is the texture preview. And below is the result once rendered.

[image: Rendered Texture]

There is no gloss at all, It is just matte. Obviously I am doing something wrong. How can I make it glossy?

Comment: If there is nothing to reflect, nothing is reflected. So you need something to reflect into your mesh. Another mesh with an emissive shader, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lemon. In the scene I have another complex object. A ball bearing. I have applied glossy textures to parts of this mesh and it is having the desired effect. I am using a a large pane above which is set to emission. So I am confused as to why this object will not go glossy as the preview suggests.

Comment: Can you show the setup of this object (the bad one) ? Nodes or shader/material panel ?

Comment: The best is to upload your blend file (or the needed part of it) here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help guys. After playing around for a while with this mesh I found that parts of it were reflective after all. But not the faces on the front. Flipping the normals and adding a bit more light gave me the result I was looking for.