# Glossy material not seen as expected

Tags: texturing

I was trying to create a pit and assign a glossy material to the hole to give an appearance of a water body.So,I added a plane subdivided it,added a subsurf modifier,extruded a middle portion inwards to make a deep hole,created a vertex group and assigned a glossy material to the group.But after rendering the effect is not as what it should have.I have attached a rendered image and the original mesh.Why is this happening? Please have a look.Thanks. Pr[image: preview render screenshot] [image: original mesh]

Comment: I think you need some environment around so that something can be reflected in the water. If not, you just have a part of the floor as reflection (like in your image)

Comment: I actually changed the color of the world a couple of times but it didn't worked completely,you see the ridge like shape at the bottom.That's the only area actually affected.

Comment: When dealing with glossy objects it is important to think of what will get reflected. If you just have an environment that is radiating light in every direction homogenously, then the reflections will be hard to tell apart from the rest of the surface. Read this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576