# How can I render objects with very shiny surfaces?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders

I am trying to render a kitchen sink / Faucet

[image: reference image]
Here is another reference image of what I want
[image: reference image]

What I have got so far is this
[image: faucet render]

**Settings for World**:

I have used an environment map HDRI with 0 saturation.

**Material settings**:

Triad with glossy, glass anisotropic and there mix shader combinations and the new principled bsdf shader too but didn't get the required result.

**Studio lights:**
Followed multiple youtube tutorials on setting up studio lights in blender but the results were not what I wanted.

---

**LEAVING CYCLES :**

Decided to try some other software
So, Downloaded Keyshot 5 but keyshot wasn't able to produce cycles like results LoL.

Not : I have always struggled to get professional quality product rendering in cycles

---

So now I'm back in cycles looking for help.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, all you need is a glossy node with roughness at about 0.01 or less

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe *specifically* how your render differs from what you want.

Comment: I don't know how it differs i just want it to look exactly the same. If you see in the reference image it looks like that the object has glass mirror property with that awesome reflection

Answer (score 8):

What you are missing is proper lighting.

The main idea is that you are not photographing an object, but what is being reflected on it.

Ditch the HDR and start from scratch (Unless you have an HDR that reproduces a photographic studio used to photograph the exact same object from the exact point of view, any other HDR will be largely useless for what you want to do)

You have an object that is reflecting the environment around it.

Start by placing a very large plane with an emitter in the scene and see how is being reflected on the surface. Move it around the scene, and notice how the placement helps you reveal or not the shape and qualities of your object. Add a second emitter or just planes with a white surface. Find the correct placement for them. You need a mostly white environment around your object, but having gaps in between the emitters/reflectors will help you reveal the contours and subtle shapes of the object.

Look for websites on how to photograph shiny objects in the real world, there are a lot of them. The same techniques apply for 3D rendering.

This link might help: http://project52pros.com/2014pros/assignment-thirty-five-photographing-a-very-shiny-object/

[image]

Comment: Also worth looking into: http://motivelife.com/topics/knowledge/199-controlling-reflections-a-tutorial-by-jeff-creech

Comment: Finally someone replied with an answer. Thank you @cegaton for your time i will try this and i'll post the results here. I am just curious about why i cannot achieve these results i badly want to improve skills  . Thanks for your help

Comment: there is no magic button or magic setting. Lighting is an art that requires lots of patience and an open mindset.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a bit left field, but tutorials on glass; e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=643CAA5Zh_8 may give you some ideas.

I was recently trying to produce the opposite effect to yours - a dull metallic sheen, and I found tweaking the material's fresnel parameter (as discussed in the linked video) useful.

Comment: I usually don't post questions on forums because i get my solutions from youtube but in this specific condition non of the youtub videos worked but thankyou for your time and suggestion