# Why is my render window always black with no realistic shine

Tags: rendering

I'm really new to rendering in blender, so I don't really know much about texturing except for UV unwraps and things like that. I only recently decided to start rendering models since I've only used my previous models for 3d printing and such. Now, for some reason, every time I try to render some image, it's just really gray and drab and unrealistic, like this (this was made with a Glass BDSF texture just so I could see how that would actually render: [image]

I know this is how it's supposed to look, but what if I wanted to create a nice bright scene, like in real life?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black. Tl;dr is add environment to make the scene behave a bit more like real life. Real life isn't flat grey background. Glass shader also is known to cause noise, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: Hmm.. @MrZak whenever I try to set a material for my background, it still looks kinda dark (see image posted

Comment: What is shine? Something that gets reflected on the surface... Where is the shine going to come from? From something you put in there to be reflected...  See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100421/shiny-black-leather-in-cycles/100422#100422 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91146/how-can-i-render-objects-with-very-shiny-surfaces/91173#91173

Comment: What did you put to the world background shader? The easiest way to lighten the scene is use hdri map (free or paid online). Not so easy way is to construct your own lighting system (several lamps / planes with emission material, you can add texture to vary emission intensity for those planes.. and so on and on. You can read about photo studio setup too)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles

Comment: http://lowel.tiffen.com/edu/lesson_lighting_glass.html