# How can I obtain similar black plastic color

Tags: materials, color

[image]
Can you tell me, how can I obtain a similar black plastic color?
Thank you

Comment: like this, but you make the diffuse shader black: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62573/7777

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100421/shiny-black-leather-in-cycles/100422#100422

Comment: Which render engine are you using?