# How would I create this material in Blender?

Tags: materials, lighting

[image]

I was wondering how I would go about creating this clean, black painted metal material in Blender.

Could it be just a simple material and it's a lot of lighting it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100421/shiny-black-leather-in-cycles/100422#100422 Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this is very simple. It's just a Diffuse and Glossy node put into a Mix Shader node. Turn the Fac on the Mix Shader towards the Diffuse side, and turn the Roughness on the Glossy shader down a bit.

[image]