# Uneven colour on mesh

Tags: mesh, lighting, color

I am making a low-poly fox and wanted to make it very bright orange like this one

[image: bright fox]

But I couldn't get this colour from just from shaders, so I tried to brighten it up. The effect was quite good but I also get a lot of red colour on some of my mesh.

[image]

How can I get a bright orange colour and get rid of that red parts?

Comment: You don't need the glossy material to have any color (white will work fine). What you need is to put more effort into your lighting setup.  Read this related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50576/1853 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91173/1853

Comment: Also that *Brightness/Contrast* node plugged that way is useless.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the high contrast value.

You will find using the Principled BSDF shader instead of using separate nodes, but if you are just learning how to use nodes, then I would suggest avoiding the color correction nodes (i.e Brightness/Contrast) and instead use the RGB color node from the input nodes.

[image: Correct node setup]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

1. turn off face orientation to get rid of the red colour.