# How to create a moving reflection on a glass surface?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, materials, node-editor

Ok, I dont know whether this is an animated material or something else, but need to know how to achieve this - or even just the static look of the white glowing line on the glass surface -

https://dribbble.com/shots/3203275-Virtual-Reality-Headset-Gifographic-element

Ive gotten the reflective glass, but how to go about the rings on top? Or the animation? In cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fake the reflection with a texture (or image).

In this example an image is used as a texture on the eyes, the coordinates
are animated.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use an object that is reflected on the surface.

Step 1: use a glossy material on the surface that you want to be reflective.

Step 2: create one or more planes with the shape you need, use an emissive material for them, and place them in a way that are visible as reflections on the surface of the reflective object.

Step 3: animate the position of the emissive plane so that it does what you need.

[image]

[image]

Read these related posts:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91173/1853

and

[Why does an object with a glossy shader render in black?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576)