# Trouble with realistic bright white plastic

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, filmic-blender, pbr

I'm having a bit of trouble creating a bright white plastic material and having it look like my reference image.

I'm using cycles, a principled bsdf shader, hdri lighting and a filmic base contrast look.

I've tried quite a few different hdri backgrounds to see if maybe the type of lighting was my issue but that didn't seem to help. I tried different studio setups, various indoor and outdoor images.

They all had the same issue of if I turned up the image background strength high enough to make the plastic material appear to be bright white, the label on the bucket would get completely blown out. (That light grey color on the label is a very important color that needs to remain visible.) Seeing as the label was getting blown out so much, I'm thinking my problem isn't with not having enough light in the scene.

Render with color correction:
[image: render with color correction]
Render without color correction:
[image: render raw]
File being used for the label:
[image: label source file]
Plastic material nodes:
[image: relevant material node]
Super basic color correction happening in the compositor:
[image: super basic color correction]
Bucket render next to a real photo of a plastic bucket (Roughly, this is what I'm hoping to achieve):
[image: reference image I'm basing the bucket off of]
Here's a [link to the project files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C0xt8Bw1opLmxfidB5bsScm_UnpCi1qJ) for reference.

So basically, I want the white plastic to be brighter like in the reference image and I also don't want the label color to get faded too much by an overly strong light source.

The way the finished image will be used will be on a website with a solid white background and printed in a catalog with a solid white background.

Please let me know if there's any more information I can provide to help make things more clear.

Comment: Look at the reference image and look for clues on how the scene is lit. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91146/how-can-i-render-objects-with-very-shiny-surfaces

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't think what is shown in reflections is necessarily the problem. If you look at the white square I was using for color correcting, it's made of a simple principled bsdf shader set to nearly pure white with a roughness of 0.75 and it is hardly any brighter than the plastic bucket. I've also tried hdr images with lots of lights setup from all angles and very little darkness and the general problem seems to persist of whites not being very bright unless the whole bucket is blown out.