# How to make material like a plastic "Soft-touch"?

Tags: node-editor

Please tell me how to make such material as the character in the picture?

Something like plastic "Soft-touch". I could not find similar material.

[image]

I tried to do it as recommended in the commentary by @Rob. But it turned out not so. Something is missing. My result: 
[image]

Comment: what material? Please display the picture in this site so that we can easily see it.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: The default Diffuse BSDF will give you that basic look, you just change the colour. To make the Diffuse BSDF more plastic add a Mix Shader and combine a Gloss Shader.

Comment: @rob. I tried to change these settings. But still something is missing. my result:       !https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qkltC5uIjN9npg2SZAAjnp4V3fLCMLRW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: On the original picture the material is more like "Soft-touch". How to achieve this effect?

Comment: try increasing the roughness in both nodes. I get a nice Soft-touch result with Diffuse BSDF Roughness 1.0 and Gloss Roughness 0.5. Try playing with both values and the Factor in the Mix Node. FYI you should be able to edit your original question and add the image. Showing what you have tried is the best way to avoid down votes.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The last close votes were cast _after_ the user has tried to make the question more conforming to this site but this effort was ignored. I think it's pretty clear now what the user is after.

Comment: Part of what is not working is the light on your scene It is all too bright and flat because of it. In the reference image there are clearly defined shadows and more contrast. The qualities of the materials depend a lot on the surrounding elements. Turn off all environment lights (in the world) and work on the lights in the scene one by one so that you understand what each light is doing.

Comment: read these related links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91146/how-can-i-render-objects-with-very-shiny-surfaces and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black