# Strange Glass Reflectivity in Wine Bottle Scene

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency, noise-reduction

I am testing out some materials and put together a simple wine scene from some downloaded assets.

This is the render:

[image: Render]

Anyway, there are parts of the render that look pretty unnatural. I've pointed them out here:

[image: Flaws]

1. The wine glass bottoms are unnaturally reflective. They almost look like metal.
2. There is some weirdness happening with the wine glass on the left.
3. There is a lot of noise only in the wine bottle side where it is reflecting the wine glasses.

Example of the noisy reflections I'm talking about (this is even after Optix):

[image: Noisy Reflections]

Here's the glass shader I'm using for the glasses:

[image: Glass Shader]

Here is my render setup and light paths:

[image: Render Setup]

I've deliberately cranked the Gloss, Transparency, and Transmission values to 32 after watching a talk about rendering glass accurately [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sv2wqwsvx-8). I've deliberately disabled caustics because well, cycles sucks at them.

Anyway, my questions:

1. How can I fix the unnatural reflections in the bottom of the wine glasses?
2. How can I denoise the reflections on the sides of the wine bottles?

Thanks for reading and for any assistance!

Edit:

[Here is the blend file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjqlze9aw7utytg/wine_collection.blend?dl=0) I had to go with Dropbox because the file was too big for Blend-Exchange. Feel free to tinker with it and optimize anything.

Comment: You could probably strip out the images and send it through blend-exchange.  The glass on the left looks fine to me, there appears to be some of the background void reflecting in it.  That IS how the stem of some of those glasses reflect, with a bowl shape like that.
Are the glasses intersecting or coplanar with the floor?

Comment: The glasses are not intersecting with the floor, and are co-planar. The base of the wine glasses are the one big thing that sticks out to me as odd. I can live with the left glass, it's actually not as bad as I thought. With regard to "background void" - I don't know how this can be since I'm using IBL as well as geometric lights.

Comment: add a hdri to scene, try several ones until you get a nice reflection, remember to make glass look less weird, use an hrdi to fake the reflections, as well if there are any objects surround it will get reflected as well in the glass...

Comment: for the noise you need more samples. Looking at your settings you are using a lot more samples for preview than for rendering, that doesn't make much sense. Use less samples to keep the interface responsive and more samples to have less noise on the render.

Comment: HDR only makes sense if you get an HDR that is a photo studio with lights for highly reflective objects...

Comment: as well use a high amount of samples for glass (usually about or so 500-1000 samples) and use adaptive sampling option to make cycles optimize a bit the render time if possible...

Comment: yep he can use light panels as well but it will make it have hard reflections, and some cases not everyone likes studio lighting in glass because of that, but it gives you more control in lighting...

Comment: hey also your refraction and refractive options are not enabled, you have to enable them if you are rendering glass...

Comment: A lot to address here in the comments. 1. There is a HDRI in the scene. 2. The HDRI is of a studio environment and set to about half strength. 3. I am using a lot more samples for preview because I have a very fast machine and I like to let it churn out more samples if I just sit there. It doesn't degrade interface responsiveness for me. 4. Increasing my samples should help, but it's strange that OptiX denoises everything BUT the reflected wine glass. 5. Michael, please read. The reflection and refraction options are for caustics. Caustics in cycles sucks and not worth it.

Comment: I see that it is not void and is one of the wine bottles :)

Answer (score 4):

A few comments:

- The bottom of the glass is flat, making a horrible thick mass of glass. Most glasses are concave like this:

[image]

[image]

- Use more samples for the render and less for the preview (to keep the interface more responsive and get better quality renders)

[image]

- Use more light bounces

[image]

- Turn Off ambient occlusion. In cycles you don't need it.
- To have less fireflies bring down the indirect light clamping. Most fireflies come from indirect sources.

[image]

- In my opinion the shader you are using doesn't improve the results of a regular glass shader.
  [image]
- Don't use overlapping geometry, it will only yield problems, like Z-figthing, where the depth buffer will have a hard time differentiating faces that are close together.

[image]

Same thing with the labels, for very thin paper it is easier to work the materials part of the bottle and not as separate objects.

As for the lighting:

It is hard (I would dare to say that is impossible) that you will find an HDR environment that suits the scene perfectly, as lighting glass and highly reflective objects is an advanced task that requires careful planing of the reflected objects on the scene. Remember that you are not lighting the scene, but creating the reflections that will bring out the qualities of the objects depicted (reflectivity, opacity, transparency, shape, volume, roundness, etc).

[How can I render objects with very shiny surfaces?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91146/how-can-i-render-objects-with-very-shiny-surfaces)

Take the advice from that link, and you disconnect the environment and start trying a single light source at the time. Make a single **very big** area light and play with it so that you understand what it does, how it is reflected on the objects and how the shapes are revealed,

[image]

[image]

Once you find a suitable placement for it, and only then, add a second one and evaluate the results until you are happy. Bring in only as many lights as you need for the effect you are after.  The more sources you bring in the more shadows and reflections you will have to control, so be judicious and spartan when it comes to lights.

[image]

Use also black elements to create dark reflections among the bright sources.

There are countless articles on the internet on how to light and photograph wine, glass and shiny objects. Do your homework and learn from those who charge a fortune to do that (and don't forget to have fun doing it).

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: As mentioned in my prior comment, I am using a lot more samples for preview because I have a very fast machine and I like to let it churn out more samples if I just sit there. It doesn't degrade interface responsiveness for me. I always max out my samples on a final render to anywhere between 1000-2000.

Comment: You need more samples on the rendered image, however many you want on the preview  is not so relevant.

Comment: Also, clamping can be detrimental to your render. Yes, it can reduce noise, but it can dull your highlights.

Comment: "You need more samples on the rendered image, however many you want on the preview is not so relevant." - I know, I just told you I max that value out when I'm going to go for a final render.

Comment: Also, I appreciate the lighting lesson, but I wasn't going for composition of the year. I was just messing with some downloaded assets to test some materials out.

Comment: Clamping can be useful, experiment with the settings until you find what works for you. Don't go with "edicts" or hearsay,

Comment: All I'm trying to do is encourage you to try different things (didn't you ask for "any assistance"?) In any case, I find it easier to understand one variable at the time before launching into multivariables and loosing control. Good luck.

Comment: No problem, makes sense. I appreciate your help greatly.