# How can I render realistically?

Tags: texturing, shaders, photorealism

I have the problem, that all my object look very unrealistic, even with shaders on them.

I broke the problem down to copying a template object to my Blender file. In the original, it looks very realistic, but after copying to my project, it also looks like crap.

I guess, that this has to do something with my world or render settings.

Can someone help me fixing this problem?

[image: original object]
[image: object copied to my project]

Comment: Yep, your environment is grey hence no reflections...

Comment: To expand a bit on this comment: A reflective surface is pretty boring, unless it has something to reflect. The easiest way to achieve this is by using a HDRI-Image as World Background. Check out HDRIhaven.com for free images you can use.

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91146/how-can-i-render-objects-with-very-shiny-surfaces/91173#91173