# Glossy object seems dark and non-reflective

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

[image]

Hi all, having trouble seeing a good render (cycles) of this donut I'm trying to make. Setting is glossy, but seems dark and non-reflective, just looks like puddy and basically all other BDSF looks basically the same. Is not glossy/ reflective!

specs:
windows 8.1
intel core i5-4210U 
GeForce 840m

Thanks

Comment: Your object is reflective, but you haven't bothered placing anything else on the scene that can be reflected on your shiny surface. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need some lightning and other objects for it to reflect off of. Additionally you could load it up in a game engine with a glossy shader and test it that way.