# Not enough reflections on a metal object

Tags: materials

So I am modelling this blade from a series. I applied the Principled BSDF shader, but no matter how much I play with it, I can't see enaugh reflections. Does anyone know how to solve this?

[image]

The Blend file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48147

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black

Comment: Turn down roughness and make the sharp edges a bit more smooth/round, e.g. using the bevel modifier. Ideally plane faces and sharp edges don't make reflections visible so well.

Comment: Bevel modifier destroys the topology of the blade, but turning down roughness really improved the reflections! https://i.cubeupload.com/i7QrlE.png

Comment: You can exlude the blade edges by using Limit Method: Vertex Group.