# same node settings different result

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

HelloEveryoneI have a problem , i am trying to understand how to use nodes , i have watched tutorial about new principlied shader , but when i am trying to make a metall object (not only metall , everything dont work )it dont reflects like a metal , then when i am downloaded a project from the internet in this project everything works well , i dont know what to make . So else , when i am trying to make the same scene with standart new scene nothing works , but with downloaded project everything working , i cant understand why , 
[image]

[image]

so in the right side of the screen is downloaded project , on the left side is my , there is same nodes , but working differntly , on other is tutorial , his example works well , my not . Can someone tell my why this is like this ? Please help me , i dont know what to do . In advance thanks

Comment: The answer lies in comparison of the editors to the right (Properties editor) > World tab from your screenshot. There is background (environment) image on the right one. And it's the one which is reflected. There is flat grey color on the left (your project). And that's what will be reflected - flat dull grey color.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black

Comment: Very Huge THANKS !!!! This helped me ! :)