# Why do glossy materials on my object look different to the material preview?

Tags: materials

So I have Imported multiple materials from different websites and tried on all of them. It never worked. If I add the Material it looks normal in the preview window:

[image: glossy/shiny and reflective]

But if I render the object I have with the material added to it it looks weird and wrong.

[image: looks weird and wrong]

I've tried multiple different materials. Chrome, Gold and Glass. All of them have the same weird look after rendering. I have the feeling it is just a little option I have to de-enable or something. Can someone help me? What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: What is the environment that surrounds the object? If you are using reflective surfaces you need to have something that gets reflected on the surface. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Answer (score 2):

Your mesh has flat faces and the preview is a sphere. The reflections look like a gradient on the sphere because of its curved surface. I am sure if you changed the shape in the preview to a cube it would look similar to how your mesh looks. Maybe you should add a bevel to your mesh to give it a more complex reflection.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the material relies on Normals.

If so, each point on a sphere has a different normal vector and can thus be assigned a different texture coordinate. On a your object all of one face and all faces facing in the same direction would have the same Normal vector. That means they also need to have the same texture coordinate assigned to.

Maybe you could include some more information of the materials you have used, so that it is easier to help you.