# How to give the color texture "light"-gloss instead of just lighten up the color of the pattern?

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, lighting

Hi blender stack exchange,
I've encountered this problem at work, where I try to make the pattern a metallic color, that should reflect the light on it, but instead it just lighten up the texture color. I've worked a little with the speccular mapping of the model, because I found some tutorials on youtube about it, but it seems like it isnt the way to solve this problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
[image]

My specc-map:
[image]

Comment: Look at real objects and see how they behave in real life.

Reflective objects will reflect the environment, and hence will look like the color of whatever is being reflected.

Metallic materials can have coloring on the reflection (normally the same base color). Dielectric objects will not.

Think of the setting for metallic in the BSDF as an on of switch. Either your object is metallic or dielectric. It is unlikely that is 0.4 metalic.

Comment: Somehow related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Comment: Watch  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H5W6C_Mbck

Answer (score 3):

The best way to test metallic or mirror reflections is to have something to reflect. Perhaps the material IS reflecting correctly.

Use an HDRI environment or other method to create a known environment with light sources, colors, etc. Then you can better judge if the material is behaving correctly to metallic shaders.

Comment: True, the problem with the project is that the only thing I am allowed to reflect in the pot, is the light :/

I got this reference photo:
https://imgur.com/R9FThXJ

Comment: Well in your example above, the light appears to be reflective, but I can't really tell. The HDRI would help you to be sure you are getting metallic reflections. In the image you show https://imgur.com/R9FThXJ it also appears to just lighten the colors. Perhaps what you like about the reflection is the bloom in the shiny areas. You can achieve that in post processing.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've bought Pro-Lighting: Studio now, which helps A LOT! :D