# White shapes showing up in render when using glossy material

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders

I am trying to create a glossy image texture for a 3d scan that I made.
When I render an image these white shapes show up. It does not happen when I only use a diffuse shader. I tried playing around whith the light but it does not help much. Currently I have one area light with a size of 0.988 and strength of 463.0. I also checked my normals and removed doubles. Does somebody know what Im doing whrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might it be that the white parts are just the faces that are reflecting the light source directly at the camera? Try changing the mesh to smooth shading instead of flat shading. It's probably not that simple, but worth a shot.

Comment: How do you know if an object is glossy? because of the reflections...Glossy is meant to reflect the environment...Those white shapes are most likely the reflection of your light source. You need to work on the ligthing. Read this related link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured out that I had to turn up the roughness of the glossy shader.