# Make a glossy, plastic-like texture with an alpha-channel?

Tags: light, shaders

I have a can model in a lighting environment. The labels I need to put on the cans have an alpha channel that need to have metal shining through it. Here is my node setup at the moment. I just started using Blender last week.

[image]

The problem is that the metal is shining through the label making it metallic-looking. In real life, the label is a wrap so there is no light reflecting back through the label. Also, I don't know how to make the transparent part (where the black text is) shine through onto a gloss BSDF metal surface.

Any tips on how to make the lighting or model look more realistic are appreciated. I'm using a three-point lighting technique. Thank you.

Edit: here are my nodes that I used for the above render.

[image]

Comment: To deal with the materials read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447. As for lighting shiny/metalic objects forget about the archaic concept of "three point lighting". You need to plan for the lights in a way that allow you to perceive the shape of the object and the qualities of the material. What matters with shiny materials is the environment reflected on the surface. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added a screenshot of the nodes I used for the render. The lighting tutorial for glossy textures is helpful as well, thank you.

Comment: Your node tree is unnecessarily complicated, or you need a much clearer way to define which parts of the mesh get what material. As for making the text reflective you need some form of mask to control which areas use just the metalic shader and which the color from the image texture. Please read the first link. posted.