# How to make my scratches have a metallic look

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, procedural

I've watched a lot of tutorials to make my scratches metallic and glossy, but my scratches only have a white color and are not reflecting anything.

My last try with that

[image]

I want to have something near this

[image]

[image]

Comment: *my scratches have only a white color and not reflect anything*... Is there an environment to be reflected by the glossy surfaces?  (see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576)

Comment: @cegaton i have environment texture already

Comment: Try the Principled Shader instead - https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/principled.html It does metallic shading, with the fresnel effects you're trying to achieve, built in.