# weird white reflection in my glossy material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

There is no bright light shining on the material so I am confused. Must be somethign wrong with my settings As you can see the mushrooms have weird white circles on them. 
[image]

Comment: Can you add the blend file? My guess is, the reflection comes from the HDRI, assuming, you are using one for your reflections.

Comment: It is the lamp of the scene. Adjust it's size to 0 so the source won't be visible.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know if an object is shiny? Because other things are reflected on the surface...

What things?

Whatever is in the environment. If there is a sun in the image used as environment or if there is a light on the scene you can expect it to be reflected on the surface.

Read: [Why does an object with a glossy shader render in black?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576)