# Rendering gold in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm tying to get expected rendering results from many days but not able to get it as seen in image. I have attached image of expected results.

[image: expected results]

Comment: Show us what you have so far and specify with what you need help - shaders, lights, scene, object?

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576