# How to increase Specular Map Gloss?

Tags: texturing

I want to make a part of my model glossy but I'm not sure how I should go about doing it.

I tried using vertex groups to separate the none-glossy from the glossy part but I get a seam.

I tried editing it in Photoshop but I can't get enough gloss. Do I just make it more and more white to make it more glossy?

Comment: The appearance of Glossy and Reflective objects depends primarily on the surrounding environment and light. Objects are not reflective unless there is something that can be reflected on the surface. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Answer (score 0):

You don't give enough precisions about what is your object: what sort of material you use, have you unwrapped your mesh, etc... but basically if some parts of your object need to be glossy and you can't use the topology to assign different materials to different faces, you should use a *Mix Shader* to mix something like a *Diffuse* (or whatever) and your *Glossy* (or whatever more compex mixes of nodes of course). Then you'll use the *Factor* socket of the *Mix* to determine what part will be glossy of diffused, for example a *Noise Texture* (if you're ok for a procedural texture, make it B&W because the *Mix* factor needs to be B&W), or an *Image Texture* (*Non-Color* mode) if you have unwrapped your mesh. It would give something like this:

[image]