# How do I get this bright colored yet plastic like reflective material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

I have this object I want to make but 
 when I try to mimic this texture with a shader in cycles [image], it just looks darker, no shine or reflectiveness, and does not have the same kind of almost plastic look to it. I am kinda new to blender 2.8 (used it for years a while back) so I am not sure if there is some kind of new techniques I am missing out on or anything.

Comment: You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information is visible in this page, instead of having users go through links just to understand what you want to do. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Thanks much better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Use a rgb in node and attach it to base color and subsurface (to keep them matched) turn up your subsurf to near max, and then adjust your roughness, specular and spec tint to somewhere in the middle of the selector value. and add to it full  clearcoat with 40ish percent clearcoat roughness.

Adjust values to fit your aesthetic

Answer (score 4):

Use the Principled BSDF shader.

Play with the **Roughness**  and **Specular** settings.

Low roughness will make the surface "shinier" "mirror like", sharp or blurry reflections.

The specular control Specifies facing (along normal) reflectivity. In other  determine how the reflected lights seem to "expand" or "spread" on the surface, so that highlights will be reflected as large surfaces or dots or points.

Note that when it comes to reflective surfaces the shader doesn't do all the job, the type of lights and their placement on the scene need to be thought out as well.

Related reading: [Why does an object with a glossy shader render in black?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576)