# How do I make an environment sphere thing? (like Blender's preview)

Tags: materials, node-editor

So, I just want to re-create a material like this one from blender [image]
Is there any way I can do it? Thank you.

Comment: This is one of blender's built in HRDI files. If you want to use them as a material on an object, they can be found in the blender folder at `../2.83/datafiles/studiolights/world`. The one you have shown is `forest.exr`.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you want to make your own HDRI - use Cycles rendering, make a sphere, give it the texture of your choice, set both the camera and the sphere to world origin, make camera  rotation x = 90 and z/y = 0, set camera type to panorama, set panorama type to Equirectanguar, render image, and save the image. You probably want the render to be rather hi-res or it will look blurry.

Comment: Also, make sure your output render is twice as wide as it is high. To get correct, uniform lighting on the image, you might have to use your texture as an emission as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy. Just have a glossy material with very little or no roughness.

There you are, done!

[image]

---

Really? But, where is the texture?

The reflections are not part of the texture, the **reflections are determined by the environment that surrounds the object**, just like in a mirror.

If you add an HDR image as your world enviroment texture it will be reflected on the surface.

[image]

More info on this link:

[Why does an object with a glossy shader render in black?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black)