# The metalic look of the material looks opaque

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, customization, pbr

My final renders look "opaque", "poor","doll", "boring" in comparison with my viewport shading and i don't know what to do to improve it. (**I use Cycles render**)

The metalic look of car with its physics and the lighting goes away in the final render... and the window is opaque black and doesn't react to light at all, al the normals are correct and i didn't use any texture for the materials, i used procedual materials with nodes, i didn't took pictures of my node trees but don't think that's the problem,(i even used **blender's Glass BSDF**) but i'll show you guys what i mean...

[image: Viewport render]

[image: Final Render Image]

Can you see the differences between the 2 images? please any tip would do just fine! here is 3 a.m. ATM and i'll go to sleep, but tomorrow i'll read the comments! good night everyone!

Comment: It looks like there is an environment texture in your viewport options but not in your world shader

Comment: If you want things to be **reflected** by the surfaces you have to put something that can be reflected, Reflections don't appear by magic. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182376/how-do-i-make-an-environment-sphere-thing-like-blenders-preview/182394#182394 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black

Comment: @Bithur there is a basic HDRI in the viewport but how do i set it up in my finawl render then?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup an environment texture.
Go to our ressources in [texture link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15358/599) and find the "HDR/JPEG Skydome Images" section. Check the links to find a HDRI environment texture and set it up in your world shader as an "environment texture" (not the usual "image texture").

in shader nodes, select world
[image: world shader]
Add an "environment texture" node and connect it to the background shader.
[image: basic world setup]
This is a basic world setup. Be aware that HDR images can be big files