# Render result is worse than render view mode. It looks very flat like 2D. How to fix it?

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view, shaders

I am a newbie, using Blender 2.91 to make a sword. But my render result looks very flat like 2D, even worse than render view image. I am not satisfied with images on render view and material view mode either. Can you tell me how to fix it? I have tried to change the viewport settings and shading nodes on world, but it still didn't come to the ideal result. (I want the blade looks metal and handle looks lead.) I spent the whole afternoon but no good effect. Can you help me take a look? [image][image]Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need an environment for the shiny surfaces to reflect.  Try applying an HDRI to your scene, like this one:  https://www.hdrihaven.com/hdri/?c=urban&h=old_hall

Comment: How to use one or more HDRI textures answered here:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris

Comment: Additional reading: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182453/the-metalic-look-of-the-material-looks-opaque/182562#182562