# When rendering, point light dosn't render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, light

I am very new to Blender and I've made a daft mistake. After rendering fine previously, my renders are now mostly black. I think they're not rendering the point light all of a sudden, like so:
[image: Black silhouette of cup against a pink wall] [image: Render of view in cycles]

The point light shows up in cycles and I've tried adding a second point light and got the same result.

If anyone has any ideas what I might have done wrong in settings, I'd really appreciate it. As I said, I was previously rendering without a problem. I suspect I've done something wrong in my settings.

[image] [image]

I'm really new, other advice I've seen about this, I've not been able to make head or tail of. If anyone knows what's going on, it would be amazing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you check your clipping distance for the camera and/or viewport. It seems there's still a light in the first screenshot, the camera is just very close to the wall.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black

Comment: Hi! Thank you for taking a look for me. I'm afraid it doesn't seem to be a clipping issue or to do with gloss as far as I can tell. I tried moving the camera back and the issue isn't apparent in cycles, only when I come to render. I'll keep looking at everything.