# Shader for reflective black plastic surface

Tags: shaders, reflection

After some research on how to model reflective plastic surfaces best I established this as my surface:
[image]

which I found in an older thread here: (https://blenderartists.org/t/cycles-glossy-plastic-material/582572/5)

If I turn the glossy BSDF dark there is no reflection what so ever.

What I want to achieve is something every close to this:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by mixing a difuse shader with a non-shader using fresnel as factor?

Comment: I would suggest you play with a princlipled shader, with a low value for roughness. Also play with the specular value. And keep in mind that highly reflective need an environment to be reflected by the surface. In that sense you are not lighting an object but lighting the objects that are reflected on the surface Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Comment: https://blog.cmog.org/2019/09/04/photographing-glass-highly-reflective-black-objects-part-1/ and https://blog.cmog.org/2019/09/11/photographing-glass-highly-reflective-black-objects-part-2/

Comment: you can use a mix between Diffuse and Glossy, the color of the Diffuse is black, the Glossy is white, plug an Input > Layer Wieght in the factor or the Mix Shader. Or Principled BSDF with black as Base Color and a very low Roughness. That would be the basic setups...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can get this result with just the principled BSDF.

If you look closely at your reference image you'll see the environment.  As mentioned in the comments those highlights are what we want to reproduce, and the ones you see in this image are coming from an HDRI environment texture.  This isn't even a particularly good HDRI for taking an image of something so round, perhaps.

You could approximate this by setting up some large area lamps focused on your object.

Comment: Thanks Allen! This is what I started with anyways. I had the feeling that the reflection was not strong enough. But maybe the environment was not the correct one. 

Do you have a hint where I might find good HDRI to start with?

Comment: HDRIhaven.com has a bunch and they are licensed CC0

Answer (score 0):

To add to Allen Simpson's answer, you can also do it with this node setup: *Diffuse* with black color and *Glossy* mixed into a *Mix Shader*, with an *Input > Layer Weight > Fresnel* as factor:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is the ebst result so far.