# Glossy Atoms using cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, reflection

I'm  new to blender and would like to reproduce the following image:
[image]

I'm currently trying to use "cycles" in blender 2.83 and was wondering which combination of "surface", "Roughness" and "IOR" would you recommend? The issue that I'm currently struggling with is the reflection, there is too much!- But I would like to make the atoms look very shiny as in the picture.

Currently I'm using:
**Surface:** Glossy BSDR
**Roughness:** 0.000

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: If you want large reflections, use a large light source https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Comment: @susu I'm using the "sun" as my light source. Would a "spot" work better?

Comment: Use "large" light source, a large area light, not a spot or point or sun... and read the suggested link.

Comment: As @susu suggests, a large area light... or maybe a plane with an emission shader. In the reference image you can clearly see that the reflected light source has a large rectangular shape.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Everything I'm doing only seems to make it worse. -[https://ibb.co/ZcSgbcY] This is my setup-[https://ibb.co/Cv01zTP] I can reproduce the image if everything is laying flat on a surface, but I must reproduce this with a molecule within a tunnel of atoms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible and slightly simpler node setup:

[image: node setup atoms]

Comment: This solves all of my problems, thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for that "plastic ball" look, go with something like this for the material. (Same material for the red, just different color). Also, you can omit the refraction shader if you want, I just find it gives more of a "pale gloss" like your reference image.

[image: Plastic]

For the lighting in my example, I used this shader for the world, using a Light Path Node to give a white background with no emission. I then handled all the lighting by putting a large emission plane above the mesh.

[image: PlasticLighting]

If you want more of a glassy metallic look, you can try a shader like this instead:

[image: Glassy]

Comment: That "plastic look" is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Why bother mixing so many different shader nodes for this "pale gloss" look? I would take the _Principled BSDF Shader_ and set the _Roughness_ to something low like 0.1 or lower like 0.05 or even less, since the reflections are quite sharp. To make them "pale" I would reduce the _Specular_ value to 0.2 or 0.1 or less instead of the default 0.5 and it should be okay.