# I’m trying to use a roughness map, but it keeps adding black spots

Tags: eevee-render-engine, pbr

So I’m trying to make a simple road. But every time I add the roughness node it creates these black spots on the road.
The goal is for them to be water, like a puddle. But it just gives me dark spots.
I’m new to this version of blender so I’m not sure what’s going on.

[image]

Any suggestions, I can show the node...tree?...If you need.
I'm also using blender 2.93.1 on Linux if that helps.

Comment: Assuming these are patches of water, and therefore 0 roughness.  You have no environment for the water to reflect.

Comment: "*But every time I add the roughness node it gives me this.*" This what? Could you elaborate on what you are unsatisfied with? What's it supposed to look like? "*I've tried everything I could think of.*" What did you think of? Could you enumerate what you have tried and why it failed? saying I tried everything tells us nothing, as it stands this question is devoid of information to allow us to help you.

Comment: Thank you both but, how would I go about adding an environment. 

And Duarte, my issue is those black spots in the road. It’s supposed to be water reflections, but the tutorial I got it from it worked first shot. I’m new to this particular version of blender, seeing as I just came from all the back to 2.79, so I’m a bit out of the loop.

Comment: A node tree would be essential to diagnose anything about your material. Also what do you expect to see in the reflection? As far as I can see there is nothing to be reflected other than the void of your scene. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Comment: Are you using Blender 2.93? There is a glitch/bug for some Intel graphic chips. If the roughness value is close to 0 it becomes pitch black. It's ok in 2.92.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your help, but unfortunately I ended up going back to an older version of blender as my computer can't handle 2.90.