# Render changes metallic objects to black, how can i change

Tags: rendering

Every time I render my project, the ovens I have modelled change to a black finish instead of the metallic stainless steel shown in the viewport. I have checked for hidden objects and there are none.

Render
[image: image of final render screenshot]

Viewport
[image: image of viewport before render]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does an object with a glossy shader render in black?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the support.  I have tried this, object is lit and there is lots for it to reflect, but still no joy.

Comment: are you using eevee or cycles? if cycles, i know that overlapping objects can cause this problem. can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: I was using cycles, here is my file, possibly full of errors as am quite new to blender, I will check for overlapping.  Many thanks