# Flat colours instead of textures

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, color

I'm experiencing a persistent issue with Blender on my MacBook Pro. No matter what material settings I use or whether I apply materials from Blenderkit, the final renders (in cycles) always appear as flat colors. I do use UV mapping, but it seems like Blender is not reading the material settings properly, resulting in a lack of realism.

Even with the default cube, I encounter the same problem. Interestingly, textures with images seem to be recognized, but pure material settings don't translate well into the final render.
This issue persists regardless of the lights I use or the samples in the render.

Has anyone else faced a similar problem? Is this possibly a computer-specific issue, or could it be a properties default in my blender? I've had the same problem with earlier versions too.

I'd greatly appreciate any advice or insights on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Feeling quite desperate at the moment. Thanks in advance!

PS: I've attached some example render images to illustrate the problem.The first image you can see how I set some "extreme" properties to the cube but the render then is like the second image. The third image you can see how the fabric material is shown.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/

Answer (score 2):

Your render appears as flat color because your environment is a flat color. In order to see the properties of your material, setup a proper scene environment by using [HDRI](https://hdri-haven.com)s for example, and go in render view, not material preview. Also make sure that the materials you are using are compatible with cycles. This is not always the case

[image]

Comment: Just a quick addition - because this is probably not obvious to @CamiCamilla or else this question would have not been asked I guess - the reason why the object shows reflections in _Material Preview_ in the viewport is that it uses a built-in default HDRI and lighting setup to showcase the material, but this environment is not available in the final render.